# Can bathroom lights be on same circuit as bedroom lights?

Tags: electrical, wiring

I know bathroom outlets must be on their own circuit.  Can the bathroom *lights* be on the same circuit as say the bedroom and hall lights?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. There's nothing different about bathroom lights vs bedroom lights. In fact, I would say it's a bad idea to tie the bathroom lights to the bathroom outlet (which should be a GFCI). Otherwise you drop your hair dryer and suddenly you're in the dark!

The only thing you might need to consider is that bathrooms tend to have exhaust fans on the same circuit as the lights. These tend to draw more amps than a light, so make sure you don't overload your circuit.

Comment: Good to know, just was confused by code.  It claims bathroom receptacles must not be on same circuit as other room and then I wondered if the light counted as a receptacle or if that only meant outlets. 

My exhaust fan is going to be low draw, I imagine most modern day fans are.  However, in the master I will have exhaust fan / heater all in one which I am running a dedicated circuit for that in itself.

Comment: @Nic you're using words inconsistent with Code.  An "outlet" describes any usage point, including hardwired ones.  a "Receptacle" is a socket you can plug appliances into.  All receptacles are outlets, not the other way round.